# Create variable from ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

I'm tring to create a variable from an ajax call (object). The call looks like this:

```
        // Get scheduled resource, id
        $('#loading').show();
        var resource_id = $.ajax({
            url: campaign_planning_base_url() + '/get_schedule_resource_id',
            data: {
                event_id: event_id
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var resource_id = data[order].resource_id;
                return resource_id;
            }
        }).done(function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
        });
```

The data I receive back looks like this:

```
[{"resource_id":"36"}]
```

I like to use the value (36) of resource_id outside this call. But when I alert the value

```
alert (resource_id);
```

I receive [object Object]. How do I get the value 36? Anyone an idea?

Comment: You can't `return` from an async call.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Ok, so how should the code look like in this situation?

Comment: Also, `console.log()` generally is more helpful than `alert()` for debugging as it often lets you examine what `object Object` really is.

Answer (score 0):

As AJAX is asynchronous, so you can't return `resource_id` to any outside. You might call a outer function within `success()` function.

```
     // Outer function
      function callOuterFunction(resource_id) {
         alert(resource_id);
      }

      $('#loading').show();
        var resource_id = $.ajax({
            url: campaign_planning_base_url() + '/get_schedule_resource_id',
            data: {
                event_id: event_id
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var resource_id = data[0].resource_id; // should be use 0 instead of `order`
                callOuterFunction(resource_id); 
            }
        }).done(function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
        });
```

Comment: @user3739279 Thanks. Don't miss to accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

`data[0].resource_id` will return 36 and writing a call back function in the success block to use this value is a better option